# xquery substring and then concat

Tags: substring, xquery, concatenation

I am trying to use `substring` and `concat` functions in an XQuery statement together.

Here is what I have:

```
fn:concat(fn:substring({data($x/DueDate)},1,4),fn:substring({data($x/DueDate)},6,2),fn:substring({data($x/(DueDate))},9,2))
```

The value for DueDate in my xml is: `2013-06-27`.

I expected the above function to return: `20130704`.

Instead, this is what I get:

```
fn:concat(fn:substring(2013-06-27,1,4),fn:substring(2013-06-27,6,2),fn:substring(2013-06-27,9,2))
```

I am confused as to why!

Comment: Please, have a look at formatting your code. Please also add a working example (well, which could work with the errors in the code), this would include some `$let $x := ...` or similar! Have a look at [ask].

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is because you haven't provided the context of your code snippet. Please give a more complete example.

Answer (score 3):

If you use it within an element, you need to surround the expression with curly parentheses, like:

```
{ 
 fn:concat(
   fn:substring(data($x/DueDate), 1, 4),
   fn:substring(data($x/DueDate), 6, 2),
   fn:substring(data($x/DueDate), 9, 2)
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your DueDate value is actually `2013-06-27`? Here is what each individual call to substring equals:

```
substring('2013-06-27',1,4)
```

=> `2013`

```
fn:substring('2013-06-27',6,2)
```

=> `06`

```
fn:substring('2013-06-27',9,2)
```

=>  `27`

`substring()` starts at the 1-indexed character number passed in the second param and copies the number of characters passed in the third param.

Comment: sorry... my Duedate is 2013-07-04. When i use this function in XSLT, i get the correct value... but when I use Xquery, it gives me back a statement and not a value....

Comment: Please provide the full XQuery code in your question. The problem appears to be that your expression is not being evaluated, but without seeing the context of the expression, we can only guess at what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up you formatting and bracketing (remove unnecessary curly brackets, remove some parentheses) and you will get some valid code:

```
fn:concat(
  fn:substring(data($x/DueDate), 1, 4),
  fn:substring(data($x/DueDate), 6, 2),
  fn:substring(data($x/DueDate), 9, 2)
)
```

There is a much shorter and more readable version, too:

```
fn:string-join(fn:tokenize($x/DueDate, '-'))
```

Or even replace using regular expressions:

```
fn:replace($x/DueDate, '-', '')
```

Comment: but it still does not work... i still get something like this: replace(2013-07-15, '-', '')

Comment: Looks to me that XML Spy only evaluates the variables. Please run `$x` and post the result somewhere on gist or pastebin or something like this (if it is longer than a few characters). And read the manual on how to run XQuery code, I never used XML Spy and don't know anything about it - the code is definitively fine.